# A question about UV wrap

Tags: uv

Hi there:) I came from Maya to blender, but I'm asking because don't know.

This 'Mark Seam' was used to spread the doughnut-shaped mesh into a rectangular shape. How can I change it to a square?
[image]

Comment: After adding a new seam, you need to re-unwrap the mesh to see the new UV map

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Follow Active Quads* unwrap mode: Select one quad to make it active then select all and *Unwrap > Follow Active Quads*, you'll have a square UV (that is cut along the seams if you've created some):

[image]